# Should I care about multi-byte character strings when using preg_match in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I can't seem to find a straight answer to this question.

If my pattern does not contain characters outside the ascii range do I need the /u modifier? The documentation seems to suggest not.  If the string being matched is UTF-8 I will still match the characters I want no?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's not whether the pattern contains utf characters, but whether the string you're matching against does. You may not be looking for non-ascii chars, but if there's any multibyte characters in the string, your pattern MAY match one of the "extra" bytes in a UTF character.

Comment: Isn't the point of UTF-8 though that multibyte sequences don't contain any 7-bit ASCII codes as any of their bytes? So if the regex engine is 8-bit clean, then wouldn't matching against ASCII characters in a UTF-8 encoded string should still be okay, regardless of the multibyte content? After all, all the multi-byte UTF-8 sequences have bytes with the first bit always set.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test out your second question because I don't have a PHP environment in front of me, but the answer to the first question is no. If you're only dealing with ASCII characters, there's no need for `/u`.

Answer (score 0):

Take `/^.$/` that matches a single character string for example.

```
var_dump( preg_match( '/^.$/u','族' ) );
var_dump( preg_match( '/^.$/','族' ) );
```

result:

```
int(1)
int(0)
```

So yes /u does make a difference even when you don't have characters outside ascii table in your pattern.